# EF6 doesn't update table when it claims it has

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, .net-4.6.1

**Problem**

Entity Framework reads from the database and then falsely logs that it has written back to the database.  I first tried using synchronous code and then async code.  Any ideas, please?

**Background**

As a first step in moving my .NET 4.6.1 MVC site away from ADO.NET to EF6, I referenced the EF library used by a sister project in the same system and have tried to read a record, update one field, and save the record back to the database.  Reading is ok, but I'm confused by what happens when I perform an update.

For the case in question, the SQL field starts off as null in an existing record, and later gets this single update to set its value.

The logger used below is Log4Net using ADO.NET.  It logs to the same database, different table.

The environments are local VS > remote IIS/SQL Server, and also published from VS so everything is remote IIS Server and SQL Server.

**Method**

```
using (var db = new EF_Entities())
{
    // Setup the logging.
    db.Database.Log = s => log.Debug(s);
    
    // Fetch record from SQL (proven working)
    TheTableObject tto = db.TheTableObject.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1234567);

    // Update SQL.
    if (tto != null)
    {
        tto.TheFieldSlashProperty = "A short string";
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

**Result**

The initial data read is correct.
The data write does not happen despite what the log says.

The logged output from db.SaveChangesAsync() is this: -

```
Opened connection asynchronously at 19/03/21 13:09:21 +00:00  
Started transaction at 19/03/21 13:09:22 +00:00  
UPDATE [dbo].[TheTableObject]  SET [TheFieldSlashProperty] = @0  WHERE ([Id] = @1)  
-- @0: 'A short string' (Type = String, Size = 50)  
-- @1: '1234567' (Type = Int32)  
-- Executing asynchronously at 19/03/21 13:09:23 +00:00  
-- Completed in 41 ms with result: 1  

Committed transaction at 19/03/21 13:09:25 +00:00  
Closed connection at 19/03/21 13:09:25 +00:00
```

Comment: are you looking in the right database :)

Comment: Good question.  Another step before asking this question was to log the connection string used in the context, and it was correct.  Local development work uses the dev server environment's database.

Comment: did you ever find out the solution for this?

Comment: Currently paused but not forgotten.  My next attempt will be against a somewhat changed codebase so my main hope is that I don't run into this problem again.  I will update the question with the situation when I get back to it.  Thanks for your interest, @Ric